# Vanilla JavaScript each function user controlled

Tags: javascript, callback, iteration

So I've written a few each functions like jQuery has, and to be honest they are nice but I got to thinking, what if the user at hand does not want to start at 0, or wants to manipulate the iterator. I've tried many ways of doing this and it seems to either crash or cause an infinite loop. Here are some examples.

```
//a being an array of elements
_$(a).each(function(i){
   console.log(i);
   i++;
});
//backend js
each:function(fn){
  var i = fn[0]; // equals the first argument in the callback
  for(i=0;i<this.length;)
     fn.call(this[i],i);

  return this;
},
```

Next Example

```
//a being an array of elements
var inta = 6;
_$(a).each(function(i){
  console.log(i); 
},inta++);
//backend js
each:function(fn,iterator){
   var len = this.length;
   var ct = iterator;
   while(ct < len)
    fn.call(this[ct],ct);

   return this;
},
```

There are a few more examples and they don't work either. So question is how do I manipulate the iterator inside the function like the first example above. If not possible that is fine just curious as to this curious possibility.

Comment: Don't think user would do that. `each` is the most generic iterator function, that honestly isn't that useful. `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `some`, `every`... all of these abstract different kinds of loops/recursion away, so manipulating the index becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Well I know this, and I'm just trying to create a generic function to use with ease for any user. It's just a small library for myself since I hate jQuery!!! Any suggestions to the best use case?

Comment: For your example you could have a let's call it preflight function which in some cases removes some of the items ( this is for the case of not starting from 0 ) and then apply the each on the new array. Also a good solution would be an agregator of functions where you could apply all the above functions metioned by @elclanrs in a specific order with specific parameters.

Comment: OK I'll take a look later. Thanks for the comments if anyone wants to answer with a strategic solution. And example I'll be here checking back, if not I'll get my example once completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I've read above from `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `some`, `every`, they just won't work with what I need since I am writing a small minimal library. So I need to know exactly what to iterate over, which in my case is `this` but only `this[INT]`. So I created an optional parameter after the function to add to the iterator by.

```js
each:function(fn,add){
        /*
           First check if add is assigned
           If it is not assign it to be 1 + 1 (i++)
           If it is, make sure it is not 0 (causing an infinite loop)
           And that will result in ( i + add)
        */
        add = 0 !== add && add || 1;
        for(var i=0;i<this.length;i = i + add)
            fn.call(this[i],i);
        return this;
    }
```

So the use case would be.

```js
var domElements = document.querySelectorAll('*'); //10 items per se
_$(domElements).each(function(i){
   console.log(i);
},2);
//logs 
//0 2 4 6 8
```

This is just a very basic iterator for now, and like I've said for a small convenient library not boogered by lots of "bull".